# How to send GitLab only schedule pipeline fail email?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I wanted to send an email when schedule pipeline is failed. I have configure `Project -> Settings -> Integrations -> Pipelines emails` but these are sending emails for all the pipelines.

I want to apply Pipeline Emails only for schedule ones.

Could you please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't possible in GitLab. There is an issue about it here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/220059

You probably have to turn off the automated GitLab emails entirely and then set up something manually in the schedule pipelines to email you, which is quite a drag but I guess should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible in GitLab. However, you can achieve this through the [unfortunately complicated] CI template. In my case, I needed to send a Mircosoft Teams notification when the pipeline failed (or succeeded).

Disclaimer: I'm not claiming the best answer.

1. Create separate repo e.g. called `ci-templates`
2. Create file `./teams/notifications.yml` and add something like:

```yaml
---

.notification_template:
  script: |
    # (preparing @payload.json is emitted)
    curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @payload.json $TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL 

.pipeline_failed:
  extends:
    - .notification_template
  rules:
   - when: on_failure
     if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/'
     variables:
       STATUS: "failed"
       ICON: "❌"
   - when: never

.pipeline_succeed:
  extends:
    - .notification_template
  rules:
   - when: on_success
     if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/'
     variables:
       STATUS: "success"
       ICON: "✅"
   - when: never

.pipeline_failed_tpl:
  extends:
    - .pipeline_failed

.pipeline_succeed_tpl:
  extends:
    - .pipeline_succeed
```

In `.notification_template` add code that will send the notification you want *manually*. In my case, this is Teams webhook with curl triggering it. It works for tags only. In your case, it will be email stuff and your rules.

3. In a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file of your repo, for each repo, sadly, you have to add as a **last stage** the following:

```yaml
include:
 - project: 'dt/ci-templates'
   ref: stable
   file: 
    - 'teams/notifications.yaml'

# (your main CI code is emmited)

teams:notifications:failed:
  stage: teams:notifications # this should be a last stage
  extends:
    - .pipeline_failed_tpl

teams:notifications:success:
  stage: teams:notifications
  extends:
    - .pipeline_succeed_tpl
```

So when your pipeline fails, the `on_failure` job will work, sending curl (or any script you want, including email sending) that will send a custom notification.

---

You can guess the drawbacks of this approach, but it also has benefits. You can customize notifications as you want and send them whenever you want. For example, I send different notifications depending on the project. See my full notification template: https://pastebin.com/raw/cpQvi45V.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old post, but posting a solution in case someone else is looking for it.

Have you tried this option?
This is available under CI/CD settings of the Gitlab project you've your pipeline scheduled.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more details on what you mean by "this options"? It is not clear as to how different from what OP has already tried.

Comment: But this sends emails for all pipelines that failed... not pipelines that are scheduled. OP and I want to only send emails if scheduled jobs fail...

Comment: apologies, I must have gone by the title. I was showing the option for notifying only when a pipeline *failed* - "Notify only on broken pipelines"